Why are types escaping namespace when included after vector header?
If I compile this minimized example with clang++:
#include <system_error>
#include <vector>

namespace MyNamespace {
  namespace ffi {
#include <sys/types.h>
  }

  void example() {
    const ffi::errno_t savedErrno = errno;
    ffi::uint uskip = static_cast<ffi::uint>(5);
    throw std::system_error(savedErrno, std::generic_category());
  }
}

I get the following errors:
clang++ -pedantic-errors -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-pre-c++20-compat-pedantic -Wno-poison-system-directories --std=c++20 -O3 -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include -MMD -MP -c -fPIC src/test.cpp -o obj/test.o
src/test.cpp:10:11: error: no type named 'errno_t' in namespace 'MyNamespace::ffi'; did you mean simply 'errno_t'?
    const ffi::errno_t savedErrno = errno;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
          errno_t
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_errno_t.h:30:32: note: 'errno_t' declared here
typedef int                    errno_t;
                               ^
src/test.cpp:11:5: error: no type named 'uint' in namespace 'MyNamespace::ffi'; did you mean simply 'uint'?
    ffi::uint uskip = static_cast<ffi::uint>(5);
    ^~~~~~~~~
    uint
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:93:33: note: 'uint' declared here
typedef unsigned int            uint;           /* Sys V compatibility */
                                ^
src/test.cpp:11:35: error: no type named 'uint' in namespace 'MyNamespace::ffi'; did you mean simply 'uint'?
    ffi::uint uskip = static_cast<ffi::uint>(5);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~
                                  uint
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:93:33: note: 'uint' declared here
typedef unsigned int            uint;           /* Sys V compatibility */
                                ^

However, if I don't include the <vector> header before the ffi namespace, then compilation works.
Essentially, why is the <vector> header preventing the types from being included into the ffi namespace?

In cases like this it is often good to look at the preprocessor output. In gcc that's -E and I believe clang will be the same. (confirmed the same)

Library headers are generally not written in such a way that they may be included anywhere except in the global namespace scope. It will cause immediate problems like compilation failure, but also less obvious problems due to ODR violations potentially causing unintended runtime behavior. For C++ standard library headers including them anywhere but the global namespace scope causes undefined behavior explicitly and for POSIX it would be expected that including them anywhere else also has undefined behavior.

How to tell where a header file is included from?

<sys/types.h> is already included implicitly through #include <system_error> and #include <vector>. The second #include <sys/types.h> in the namespace MyNamespace::ffi is prevented by the header guards in <sys/types.h>.

You type faster than me. Lame reason for an upvote.

I was typing a comment, then decided to copy a comment into an answer.

This is one of the rare times where I started writing an answer before writing a comment.

"The second #include <sys/types.h> in the namespace MyNamespace::ffi is prevented by the header guards in <sys/types.h>." - and as such, you should move <sys/types.h> outside of the namespace, and then use typedef or using statements inside the namespace, eg: #include <sys/types.h> ... namespace MyNamespace { namespace ffi { using errno_t = ::errno_t; using uint = ::uint; } ... } etc
